# Force browser to render with en locale

Tags: html, django, browser, lang

I am dealing with a browser rendering problem that renders decimal points using a comma, instead of a dot, in some languages. This breaks some javascript code.

I tried setting lang attribute to en on the script/HTML tags and it appears not to work, and the browser still renders decimal points using a comma.

My question is there a way to override the Accept-Language header, and set it to only use en?

I am using Django. Otherwise dealing with this case directly in the code seems the only way.

The Problem:

> 99,00

What I want:

> 99.00

Comment: Can you give us a broader description of the problem? How are numbers created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the locale settings explicitly on settings.
Django gives you a lot of possibilities when it comes to these settings.

```
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = '.'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

I believe that using the `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR` setting might solve your issue.
Here is the link to documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#decimal-separator

Comment: just what i needed, the USE_L10N need also be False